# Dedicated network for MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I am setting up a mysql master-master GTID replication. I configured all prerequisites and my current replication config looks like

```
Node 1:
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'NODE2_IP',MASTER_PORT = 3306,MASTER_USER = 'repl_user',MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password',MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1;

Node 2:
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'NODE1_IP',MASTER_PORT = 3306,MASTER_USER = 'repl_user',MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password',MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1;
```

Is it possible to use a dedicated network for replication traffic. What are the prerequisites for that and what are the changes required from mysql replication perspective.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found out the option

**MASTER_BIND** is for use on replication slaves having multiple network interfaces, and determines which of the slave's network interfaces is chosen for connecting to the master

Thanks